# Picture output.(Java)

Tags: java

I have a problem with the code, can you tell what's wrong with it?

Here's the code:

```
package Game;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Game extends JPanel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private BufferedImage image;

    public static final int WIDTH = 600;
    public static final int HEIGHT = 500;

    public static void main(String avg[]) throws IOException {
        Game abc = new Game();
    }

    public Game() {
        try {
            JFrame frame = new JFrame();
            frame.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
            frame.setVisible(true);
            frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.BLACK);
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

            image = ImageIO.read(new File(
                    "C:\\Users\\дНМ\\workspace\\Game\\image\\heroG.png"));
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            // handle exception...
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null); 
    }

}
```

I get a window, but the picture does not show.If you write what the problem is, it would be just great!And if you still have fixed - complemented the code, it would be all super!

Thank you for attention.

**UPD**

Thank you all.
Updated the code like this, the image is brought out, but the background is no longer black!

```
public Game() {
        try {   
            image = ImageIO.read(new File(
                    "C:\\Users\\дНМ\\workspace\\Game\\image\\heroG.png"));

            JFrame frame = new JFrame();
            frame.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
            frame.setVisible(true);
            frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.BLACK);
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

            frame.add(this);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

How to return me a black background?)

**UPD2**

Here is a code works for me, thank you all.

```
package Game;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Game extends JPanel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private BufferedImage image;

    public static final int WIDTH = 600;
    public static final int HEIGHT = 500;

    public static void main(String avg[]) throws IOException {
        Game abc = new Game();

    }

    public Game() {
        try {
            JFrame frame = new JFrame();
            image = ImageIO.read(new File(
                    "C:\\Users\\дНМ\\workspace\\Game\\image\\heroG.png"));

            frame.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
            frame.setVisible(true);
            frame.getContentPane().add(this);
            this.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null); // see javadoc for more info on the
                                        // parameters
    }

}
```

Comment: stack overflow not here to solve your home work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the instance of `Game` and invoke `setVisible` after the component has been added so that the `JPanel` so that the window contains the component and the frame can correctly paint added components

```
frame.add(this);
frame.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: Lost black background

Comment: @IvanCern because you didn't set the background on the JPanel. Use `this.setBackground(Color.BLACK);` instead of `frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.BLACK);`

Comment: or simply `setBackground(Color.BLACK);`

Answer (score 0):

> can you tell what's wrong with it

This is clearly wrong:

```
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        // handle exception...
    }
```

This should be at least:

```
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

To be able to see if you have an error...

The issue why your picture does not appear might be that you didn't specify add the Game component to the ContentPane of the frame:

```
frame.getContentPane().add(this);
```

Comment: The picture itself is not output

Comment: Lost black background

Answer (score 0):

Set `setVisible` As TRUE

```
    import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
    import javax.swing.*;

    public class ImageInFrame {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
            String path = "Image1.jpg";
            File file = new File(path);
            BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(file);
            JLabel label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(image));
            JFrame f = new JFrame();
            f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            f.getContentPane().add(label);
            f.pack();
            f.setLocation(200,200);
            f.setVisible(true);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I need to have it drawImage.I am so it will be easier to coordinate